# MissingMandatoryParametersException: Some mandatory parameters are missingto generate a URL for route

Tags: symfony, twig

It seems that I am missing something here and I am keep getting the following message:

## An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("fooId") to generate a URL for route "foo_edit".") in AdminFooBundle:Default:base.html.twig at line 1. ##

This is the Controller's action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{fooId}/edit", name="foo_edit", requirements={"fooId" = "\d+"})
 * @param $fooId
 *
 * @return View
 */
public function editFooFormAction($fooId)
{
    $foo = $this->getFooRepository()->findOneBy(['fooId' => $fooId]);

    return $this->render(
        "AdminFooBundle:Competition:show_foo.html.twig",
        ['foo' => $foo]
    );
}
```

And this is my twig file:

```
{% extends 'FooAdminToolBundle:Default:base.html.twig' %}

{% block inner_main %}
{{ parent() }}

<form data-spy="scroll" data-target="#affix-nav" action="{{ path('foo_create') }}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" style="position: absolute; left:-10000px;"></button>
    {% include 'FooAdminBundle:Foo:foo_data.html.twig'%}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add new foo</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My guess is the issue lives in extending  Default:base.html.twig, but I cannot see something right now:

```
    {% set currentPath = path(app.request.attributes.get('_route')) %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <title>    {% block title %}Admin Tool{% endblock %}</title>

    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    {% endblock %}

    {% block headcss %}
    {% endblock %}

    {% block headjavascripts %}
    {% endblock %}

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#affix-nav">

    {% include 'FooAdminBundle:Default:navbar.html.twig' %}

    <div class="container">

        {% block main %}{% endblock %}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                {% block inner_main %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div id="options" data-spy="affix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!-- /main -->
```

Comment: I can't see any request to `foo_edit` route in your twig.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have a valid for parameter $fooId. In your route is mandatory, and maybe because is missing, that error is thrown.